Is there any way to fetch a git branch with history only going back to a specified ref?
I have some very long-lived git base branches, that have tens of thousands of commits going back years, with gigabytes of data created and then later deleted over time. I'm trying to optimize an existing Github Actions workflow we have, that auto-rebases certain open PR feature-branches in response to changes in these long-lived branches. As the base branches have grown heavier over time, these workflows take longer and longer to run, mostly due to having to download and replay this long fetch history.
I think the git fetch of the long-lived branch could be a lot faster if it was more shallow. The fetch sadly can't just be for the latest commit, as I need "enough" history in the branch to make the rebase against the feature branch possible. And I can't set a fixed shallow depth, as our feature branches can be arbitrarily long-lived.
My goal, then, is to find a way to fetch "just far enough" into the history of both the base and feature branches, to have the local commits necessary to rebase one against the other.
Let's presume that for a branch base, and a set of branches feature-1 through feature-N, I already have a branch nca whose tip points to the nearest common ancestor of {base, feature-1, feature-2, ..., feature-N}. (I already have modified the Github Actions workflow to calculate and push such a branch.)
Let's also presume I can efficiently fetch just this tip ref (using e.g. git ls-remote) at the start of the workflow.
Given that I have this ref, is there any way to use the ref to get git fetch to give me a "shallow fetch" — where rather than a fixed depth, the fetch will be limited to whatever depth is required in each branch to get local access to the "slices" of commit history from the ref to the tip of the branch? Something like git fetch --shallow-since=[date], but with a ref instead of a date?

This is how you can get the timestamp of a ref:
date -d "$(git show -s --format=%ci 93ddecac427bc01568b6eee7ba31c02d37e3f066)" +%s

And then you can either embed this result into your shallow-since fetch, or save it into a variable and embedding it that way, depending on your preference.
